# Un-updated rows using python code

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm using python 3 for coding, and when I'm asking to update the database if there are None value on the elevation column, many cases are not updated (which they have  None values).

```
import psycopg2 as p
conn = p.connect("dbname=Chicago user=postgres password=admin host=localhost ")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from chicago_2po_4pgr group by id")
nbrows = cur.rowcount
rows = cur.fetchall()

elev=result[1].text
x=result[0][1].text
y=result[0][0].text

//I'm getting elev,x and y after using api google elevation request

for j in range (0,nbrows):
            xs=str(rows[j][14])
            ys=str(rows[j][15])
            xt=str(rows[j][16])
            yt=str(rows[j][17])
            el_1=str(rows[j][30])
            el_2=str(rows[j][31])
            if x==xs and y==ys and el_1=='None':
                cur.execute("update chicago_2po_4pgr set elev_1=%s where 
                 x1=%s and y1=%s" %(elev,xs,ys))

            if x==xt and y==yt and el_2=='None':
                cur.execute("update chicago_2po_4pgr set elev_2=%s where 
                x2=%s and y2=%s" %(elev,xt,yt))
```

I'm really wondering why the update function does not work for some record, even when the x and y coordinates are present on the dataset and the elevation column is null for these coordinates.

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing for NULL can be done in 2 ways: `el_2 == None` or `el_2 is None`

What you are doing is checking if value of el_2 equals `string` 'None'.